# Using stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for an active state on a list of URL

Tags: php, stripos

I have this to add an active state on a navigation

```
<li <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="/page">Page</a></li>
```

But I need to add a few pages for the active state to trigger. Something like:

```
<li <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/page', '/another', '/somethingelse') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>><a href="/page">Page</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use pattern matching with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if ( preg_match(
        '/\/(page|another|somethingelse)/', // any regexp here
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
     )
) { 
  echo ...
}
```